# CSS: UL bullets are hidden

Tags: css

I have a basic CSS question.

I have a list, but I can't get the bullets to show ..

Here is a [screenshot](http://see.weareinto.com/BtJq)

The only way i can get them to show is by making the position set to `inside`, but I want it set to `outside` as it is.. no matter how much padding or nmargin i add to the left, I can't seem to get the bullets to show.

Here is the CSS applied.. I have applied it to everything.. the UL, the LI, etc

```
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: square;
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class="static" style="display: block; ">
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/group-medical-plans.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Group Medical Plans</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/self-funding-administration.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Self-Funding Administration</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/workers-comp.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Workers Comp</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/cobra-administrative-services.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">COBRA Administrative Services</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/medicare-plans.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Medicare Plans</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/individual-family-plans.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Individual-Family Plans</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/selling-area-maps.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Selling Area Maps</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
        <a class="static menu-item" href="/producers/products-services/Pages/provider-networks.aspx"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Provider Networks</span></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT

Okay, it still isnt working, here is my LESS

```
ul {
    background-color: @color-grey-border;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    list-style-type: square !important;
    list-style-image: none !important;
    list-style-position: outside !important;
    overflow-x: visible !important;
    margin-left: 30px !important;

    li {
        padding-left: 30px !important;
        list-style-type: square !important;
        list-style-image: none !important;
        list-style-position: outside !important;
        overflow-x: visible !important;
        margin-left: 30px !important;

        .menu-item {
            border-bottom-color: #fff !important;
            padding: @base * .5 0 !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT -

Here are 4 more screenshots

http://see.weareinto.com/BtJh - http://see.weareinto.com/BtRh

http://see.weareinto.com/BsvD - http://see.weareinto.com/Bsjs

Comment: You will have to show some CSS code you have on the ul/li elements..

Comment: Do you have `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` element?

Comment: I do! lemmie see if that fixes it // post ur comment as an answer!

Comment: Bummer! didnt work!, i edited the post tho

Comment: Try adding `float: none;` to the ul opening tag (see my latest comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was some Javascript that was being applied after load :\
I hate inheriting projects where people solve problems in the wrong way..

Answer (score 10):

Having these styles should be enough:

```
ul {
    list-style: square outside;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/3dYKK/

If that's not working, you need to post more of your CSS or build a sample jsfiddle page so we can help.

Edit: Here's the new jsfiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/3dYKK/3/ It contains your CSS and it still works. It's something else that's influencing the styles, not what you posted - do you have a real page where we can see the problem?

Comment: Could you try to remove `width: 100%` from your ul?

Comment: Try changing the ul markup to this: `<ul class="static" style="display: block; float: none;">`.

Comment: I have no control over the HTML :(

Comment: That was just an example of doing it. Just add this rule to the CSS: `ul.static { float: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.a {
      list-style-type: circle;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="a">
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Coca Cola</li>
 </ul>
```