# why will v-html will not render unordered list <ul>...</ul>

Tags: vuejs3

I have a vue 3 application that has some richtext fields generating html stored in the db. I then display that content using the `<span v-html="richText" />`

for some reason the `<ul> ... </ul>` elements don't get rendered. I have also tried setting the innerHtml of an element with the same result

What the result should look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjRQ.png)

what it actually renders
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEZwj.png)

Sample code

```
<template>
  DIV ELEMENT
  <div id="htmlElement" />

  V-HTML
  <div v-html="html" />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HtmlElement',
  props: {
    html: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data: () => ({}),
  mounted() {
    const e = document.getElementById('htmlElement');
    if (e && this.html && this.html.length > 0) {
      e.innerHTML = this.html;
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

If I replace all the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags in the string it works
`e.innerHTML = this.html.replaceAll('<ul>', '').replaceAll('</ul>', '');`

Any suggestions on  what I am missing would be great

Comment: Did you actually check the DOM?  They look rendered to me, they're the text items "list item 1", "list item 2", "list item 3", right?  If the issue is the missing bullet point, it could be a CSS issue.  They look like they could be off screen.  Try just adding `padding-left: 30px` to the ul or its container.

Comment: @yoduh you are right the items are rendered but not the bullets. As this html is generated by the quill rich text editor I will hunt down what style is moving the bullets off the screen. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: UL bullets are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160401/css-ul-bullets-are-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

@yoduh put me on the right track.
The bullets were being rendered but not shown because of some higher level margin and padding styles.

to solve the issue I had to change the vuetify margin and padding classes I was using.